# CSS wont apply to ejs files

Tags: css, node.js, ejs

My CSS code won't apply to an ejs file. But for some reason, it applies to every other ejs file. My app structure is ...
(using nodejs and express)

```
app.js
util
routes
controllers
models
public
 -css
   -main css, etc
   -admin css folder
     -admin-page1 css
     -admin-page2 css 
views
  - includes (contains header/end.ejs)
  - admin folder 
    - admin-page1 ejs
    - and so on..
```

in app.js, i have:
   app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,"public")));

in my ejs files, I do include my ejs header file.

my header ejs file in my includes folder contains all the CSS files

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title><%=pageTitle%></title>  
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "css/main.css" />
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "css/bio.css" />  
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "css/admin/admin_request-list.css" />  
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "css/amin/admin_single-request.css" />  
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "css/quote_form.css" /> 
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "css/hp-services.css" />
```

I tried everything and like I said it doesn't work for one admin ejs file but I copied code from one ejs file and pasted into this one to see if it some error I have done but it still doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated! I'm just trying to get past this annoying step

Comment: what is the url you are visiting?. check if the css files are present in the network calls and on the page source.

Comment: You should use absolute path starting with a `/` like so `/css/main.css` otherwise if you are on page let's say `example.com/admin` the link `css/main.css` points to `example.com/admin/css/main.css`. btw if you check devtools you should see an error like `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution to use Imoport files on main CSS file

```
        @import url("bio.css");
        @import url("quote_form.css");
        @import url("hp-services.css");

        @import url("admin/admin_request-list.css");
        @import url("admin/admin_single-request.css");
```

Comment: What does that do? How does it answer the question? Don't just blurt out code. Explain yourself! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Remove all stylesheet links from your header ejs file, keep only the main.css link. Then insert the import code on the very top the main.css.

Answer (score 0):

You need just get rid of type="text/css". For example, this link:

```
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "css/main.css" />
```

we change to this one:

```
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "css/main.css" />.
```

Comment: Without type="text/css" <link rel = "stylesheet"  href = "css/main.css" />